# Why does 120V line measure 26V?

Tags: voltage

[image]

The red wire has fed to fluorescent lights / LEDs for decades with 120V.  When the circuit breaker is open it reads 6V, breaker closed is 26V AC (Fluke DVM) between the red and white wire: no load open circuit as show in photograph.

For some reason the black wire is always powered with 120V.

What would cause the voltage to drop to 26V?

Please include any applicable test procedure with an answer.  Thank you

Comment: What reference are you using? The white neutral? Is the red actually connected to anything at the other end. When I used to install ceiling lights in custom homes they all had a extra conductor (red) incase someone wanted to change from just a light fixture to a fan/ light fixture, it was one of many “selling points” when we built “spec” homes and some higher end track homes. It may be a phantom voltage or that would be my guess with the information provided.

Comment: What are you using to measure that? DVM's are too sensitive and tend to pick up crosstalk from other wires as mystery voltage. But there's nothing there.

Comment: The light was powered by the red wire and it has stopped working recently?  Was the black capped off and powered by another breaker?

Comment: @Crip659 Yes the light was powered by a switched red wire and recently stopped working.  The black wire is not controlled by a switch, capped and its breaker is unknown.

Comment: Think you know what comes next, go though the circuit backwards to find the broken connection/wire.  Voltage you are reading probably just phantom, especially that low.  Might find fried mouse.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine. I think you are indicating that the reading are misleading and that there is no voltage?   Furthermore, I need to get trace the red wire to find the other end and verify that it is connected to in what is in all likeliness ROMEX wiring?

Answer (score 2):

When you open up a box to do a specific task, you often find wires that are either totally unrelated to your task, or dual-use: used by your task and also other unrelated things.   And this is where the novice messes up, because they don't care about the unrelated other things.

The classic scenario is going to change a lamp, and finding

- A **switched-hot** wire that is only for the lamp
- An **always-hot** wire that is NOT for the lamp (it serves other things, possibly the switch)
- **Neutral wires** that serve both the lamp and other things.

You have all of the above in this box.  The black wire is unrelated to your project and wasn't connected to the lamp before, best to leave it the bleep alone.  If you find it is energized even when the "light" circuit breaker is off, then it is fed from a different circuit breaker - if it shares the neutral, it is a "Multi-Wire Branch Circuit" that is not properly handle-tied - that should be corrected!

However what you usually find in lamp boxes is an always-hot wire that is on the same circuit as the light, but is going onward to supply other lights or receptacles.

It's perfectly common in conduit installations to find wires unrelated to your circuit passing through a box.